# "ORA-00903: invalid table name" from JScript, works good from Toad

Tags: javascript, oracle, jscript, toad, testcomplete

I have a query to update state_id for one row in a table:

```
UPDATE EVENTS
   SET final_name = 'bla-bla-bla',
       transaction_Date =
          TO_DATE ('2014-09-08T03:29:57', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:ss'),
       state_id = '90'
 WHERE     ROWNUM <= 1
       AND state_id = '2'
       AND ufm_id IS NOT NULL
       AND violation_event_id IS NOT NULL
       AND violation_Event_type_id = '1';
```

When I am executing this query from Toad everything works like a charm (with commit or without).
When I generate exactly, double checked, the same query from JScript (in SmartBear TestComplete) I am getting an error:
ORA-00903: invalid table name.
I copy generated query from debug output, paste it to Toad - works well.

Found the mistake: RTFM - I cannot update by "`UPDATE..`." query execution, in adodb I need to read recordset by "`SELECT..`.", assign new values and execute recordset.update.
[Recordset examples](http://www.georgehernandez.com/h/xComputers/Databases/ADO/ADOObjects/Recordset.asp)

Comment: Jscript connection to a different database or schema?  Permissions?

Comment: It's likely a driver problem.  That said... why are you passing the same query in... shouldn't you be using a paramaterized query and call a procedure to do the update?  To troubleshoot: eliminate all but the final_name on the update keeping where criteria.  Does it work then? add state_Id.. work again?  now add date... guess what doesn't work does it?  Why?  likely how the driver handles the ' vs " in the date fields.  A paramaterized query would likely bypass this troublesome issue.  I could be wrong though... so troubleshoot using technique mentioned.

Comment: Are they same users - Both Toad and jscript users?? If not, check the permission to SELECT on the tables and GRANT access if needed

Comment: I am not familiar with JScript so ignore if this is off-base, but make sure that both Toad and JScript are connected as the same schema and have the same value for the current_schema alter session parameter. Try modifying your SQL to fully qualify the table name with its schema.

Comment: Try specifying the table name with its schema: <schema_name>.EVENTS

Comment: 1. yes, the same user and schema. 2. yes, I specify full name <schema>.<table> in the query, just removed it from the post. 3. will try to debug according to comments, definitely think about driver, will try another one.